# Python - which is considered better for scraping: selenium or beautifulsoup with selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, webdriver

This question is for Python 3.6.3, bs4 and Selenium 3.8 on Win10.

I am trying to scrape pages with dynamic content. What I am trying to scrape is numbers and text (from http://www.oddsportal.com for example). From my understanding using requests+beautifulsoup will not do the job, as dynamic content will be hidden. So I have to use other tools such us selenium webdriver.

Then, given that I will use selenium webdriver anyway, do you recommend ignoring beautifulsoup and stick with selenium webdriver functions, e.g.

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q"))
```

Or is it considered better practice to use selenium+beautifulsoup?

Do you have any opinion as to which of the two routes will give me more convenient functions to work with?

Comment: selenium can find by xpath, css_selector, etc so mostly you don't need BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Beautifulsoup

[**`Beautifulsoup`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a powerful tool for **Web Scraping**. It use the **urllib.request** Python library. **`urllib.request`** is quite powerful to extract data from static pages.

### Selenium

[**`Selenium`**](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/) is currently the most widely accepted and efficient tool for **Web Automation**. Selenium supports interacting with `Dynamic Pages, Contents and Elements`.

### Conclusion

To create a robust and efficient framework to scrape pages with dynamic content you must integrate both **`Selenium`** and **`Beautifulsoup`** in your framework. Browse and interact with dynamic elements through **`Selenium`** and scrape the contents efficiently through **`Beautifulsoup`**

### An Example

Here is an [**`example`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47869382/scraping-contents-of-multi-web-pages-of-a-website-using-beautifulsoup-and-seleni/47871704#47871704) using **`Selenium`** and **`Beautifulsoup`** for **`Scraping`**

Answer (score 1):

`Selenium` has many [selectors](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

```
find_element_by_id
find_element_by_name
find_element_by_xpath
find_element_by_link_text
find_element_by_partial_link_text
find_element_by_tag_name
find_element_by_class_name
find_element_by_css_selector

# and 

find_elements_by_name
find_elements_by_xpath
find_elements_by_link_text
find_elements_by_partial_link_text
find_elements_by_tag_name
find_elements_by_class_name
find_elements_by_css_selector
```

so mostly you don't need `BeautifulSoup`.

Especially `xpath` and `css_selector` can be useful.