# How to speed up my Python webscraper in Selenium

Tags: performance, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I created a webscraper that uses Selenium and BeautifulSoup to scrape the name and price of products on Coolblue.nl (a Dutch online electronics marketplace) using a product-specific URL. Even though I made the webbrowser headless, it still takes quite some time to get the product name and price. How can I speed up the webscraping process? Is Selenium the right way to go about this?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import json



def get_price(url):
    # Tweaks options of the ChromeDriver used by Selenium
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # Disable the GPU and make a 'headless' request to the URL
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('disable-gpu')
    # Headless requests are often blocked by websites. The 'user-agent' is set to read like a request sent by a browser.
    options.add_argument('user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;Win64) AppleWebkit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.82 Safari/537.36')
    # ChromeDriver is launched with options added as an argument
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
    # Driver send a get request to the URL
    driver.get(url)
    # Driver gets the page source data
    data_source = driver.page_source
    # BeautifulSoup parses the page source data with the HTML parser
    parser = BeautifulSoup(data_source, 'html.parser')
    # The HTML parser finds the name and current price of the product and returns it using json string commands
    json_str = parser.find('script', {'type': 'application/ld+json'}).get_text()
    json_str = json_str.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '')
    data = json.loads(json_str)
    name = data['name']
    price = data['offers']['price']
    return str(name), float(price)
```

I have tried using requests, but the request to Coolblue.nl does not work.

Comment: I got it to work with requests by setting the user-agent to 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36'

Answer (score 1):

Precisely, to answer if [*Selenium*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871704/7429447) the right way to scrape any webapplication, would much depend on the underlying application architecture.

If you have to scrap pages with static elements, [***Beautifulsoup***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983631/7429447) would provide the much needed performance. But if the elements on the page are dynamically generated either through:

- [*JavaScript*](https://www.javascript.com/)
- [*AngularJS*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447)
- [*ReactJS*](https://reactjs.org/)
- [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)
- [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/)
- [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)
- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Then you need to allow the dynamic components to get [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) within the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp). In those cases, there can't be any better approach then using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447).

Comment: Thanks. The page has static elements, but when I use the requests module it does not return anything - I get a 403 error. Is there anyway to avoid this, or is Selenium the only option in that case?

Comment: @stilts15 Use Selenium to initiate the session and then use Beautifulsoup to scrape.

Comment: Thanks again for your help and quick response. I actually got it to work with requests. I set the user-agent to 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36' and now it works.