# How to choose a good scraper based on content type?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I want to choose a scraper based on a given URL.
but the problem is sometimes beautifulsoup is unable to scrape some js protected pages.
In this situation I use selenium instead of bs4.
but I want to know how to detect content type in websites and based on that type choose right scraper automatically.
Please give me an approach to do this task.

Comment: I don't want to recommend a library or something and I mentioned to libraries myself, the question was about an algorithm to separate websites based on static or dynamic content types.

Comment: What I do is open the page in chrome with network tab open and then search for the content I want. If it's in the main doc I use something like BS and if it's in a fetch possibly something like Selenium

Answer (score 1):

To choose an efficient scraping tool you need to have a deeper look into the [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) rendered by the browsing client.

---

### Solution

If you have to scrape pages with static elements, [***Beautifulsoup***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47983631/7429447) would provide the much needed precision and performance.

But if the elements on the page are dynamically generated either through:

- [*JavaScript*](https://www.javascript.com/)
- [*AngularJS*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73241154/7429447)
- [*ReactJS*](https://reactjs.org/)
- [Vue.js](https://vuejs.org/)
- [Ember.js](https://www.emberjs.com/)
- [React Native](https://reactnative.dev/)
- [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)
- [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Then you need to allow the dynamic components to get [rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47237075/7429447) within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes). In those cases, there can't be any better approach then using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447).

Comment: Not always the case. If it's dynamically generated I'd first check to see if there's an api to get the data directly, I would then check if it's embedded in a `<script>` tag within the html. Only if bot of those are a no, would I look to use Selenium.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but my question is how to detect and separate content types from static or dynamic rendered to choose a related scraper automatically?

Comment: I want to find a way to choose between selenium and BS4 based on content type.

Comment: _`content type`_ is an abstract word possibly technology _agonistic_

Comment: I need to find an element to try for detect by beautifulsoup and if it wasn't exist on bs4 try by selenium instead. I prefer to use beautifulsoup because of execution speed and etc at the first order. Please suggest me an html or etc element to use as the Anchor to choose a specific scraper.

Comment: I want to switch between BS4 and Selenium automatically based on Content Type (DOM Tree)

Comment: [BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47871704/7429447) and [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) uses different techniques/algorithms. You just can club them up.